# Akeneo API - Getting children product models

Tags: symfony, akeneo

I'm on Akeneo 2.3 & have a product structure as

> Product Model (Master) -> Product Model (Color) -> Product (Size)

I'm trying to call this endpoint

```
{{url}}/api/rest/v1/product-models?search={
    "parent": [{
        "operator": "=",
        "value": "DRZ9186"
    }]
}
```

However, I'm getting

```
{
    "code": 422,
    "message": "Filter on property \"parent\" is not supported or does not support operator \"=\""
}
```

Now I'm not quite sure whether parent is genuinely not supported via the filter as they are not mentioned here https://api.akeneo.com/documentation/filter.html

Pretty sure it comes down to `\Pim\Bundle\ApiBundle\Checker\QueryParametersChecker::checkPropertyParameters` but that's where I couldn't move further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "parent" property is not available right now on the Akeneo Web API.

You are right about `QueryParametersChecker::checkPropertyParameters`. It checks which properties can be used based on its [service definition](https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/blob/2.3/src/Pim/Bundle/ApiBundle/Resources/config/checkers.yml#L33). As you can see, `parent` is not one of the authorized fields.

By the way, even if it was available, there is currently no operator `=` for the property `parent`. Available operators are `IN`, `EMPTY` and `NOT EMPTY`. So instead of:

```
search={"parent":[{"operator":"=","value":"DRZ9186"}]
```

the correct request would be:

```
search={"parent":[{"operator":"IN","value":"[DRZ9186]"}]
```

Don't hesitate to open a feature request on [Akeneo GitHub repository](https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/issues), describing your use case. Akeneo product owners will certainly be interested.

Comment: Thank you. Wondering if you have any pointer if I'm happy to take this on myself? Just after something like what class/method should I be looking into extending/overriding.

Comment: No need to override a class. If you want to add it as a custom code in your project, you need first to redefine the 3 services in you project application: `pim_api.checker.query_parameters`, `pim_api.checker.query_parameters_product`, and `pim_api.checker.query_parameters_product_model`. Add `parent` in the array of their last argument. This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks @Damien, I'll give it a go :) appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi @Damien, this seems to be working quite well on product-models endpoint - but doesn't seem to do the filtering (returning empty items list) for products endpoint. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @AlvinNguyen. There are 3 different elasticsearch indexes in Akeneo: "akeneo_pim_product", "akeneo_pim_product_model", and "akeneo_pim_product_and_product_model" (this last one is used in the datagrid).
The content of these indexes come from normalizers. If you look at the product property normalizer https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/blob/master/src/Pim/Component/Catalog/Normalizer/Indexing/Product/PropertiesNormalizer.php, you'll see it does not handle the "parent" field (which in the product table is called "product_model", not "parent").

Comment: If you want the parent filter to work, you'll need to override this normalizer (its service is "pim_catalog.normalizer.indexing_product.product.properties") and add the "parent" field to elasticsearch, filling it with the code of the product model that is the parent of your product, or with null if the product has no parent.